# How to use SSL with Django app (deployed using mod_wsgi and virtualenv)

Tags: django, apache, ssl, mod-wsgi, virtualenv

Disclaimer: I don't really know what I'm doing, so I may have phrased things wrong. I've also never asked/answered a question on here before!

I have a Django app running on Apache that I deployed using mod_wsgi and virtualenv. I want some parts of the app to use SSL, however when I install the SSL certificate, the https URL goes to the index.html file from my public_html folder instead of the app (which is outside of public_html)

For example, visit https://tradekandi.com. That URL is just a basic HTML file: public_html/index.html
Then visit http://tradekandi.com. That's my Django page (in maintenance mode).

I've searched stackoverflow and Google all day. I've tried removing the documentroot from the virtual hosts file but that did nothing. I tried adding a SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=1 line to it but that did nothing either.

My virtual hosts file has these lines in it:

```
SSLEngine on 
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/tradekandi.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/tradekandi.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/tradekandi.com.cabundle
```

Whenever I make any changes, I restart apache and "touch" the app's wsgi file.

How can I make the https URL load the Django app? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

More of httpd configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 69.65.42.153:80>
ServerName tradekandi.com
ServerAlias www.tradekandi.com
DocumentRoot /home/trade/public_html
ServerAdmin webmaster@tradekandi.com
UseCanonicalName Off
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/tradekandi.com combined
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/tradekandi.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
## User trade # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup trade trade
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
    SuexecUserGroup trade trade
</IfModule>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/trade/public_html/cgi-bin/

Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/*.conf"  
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/*.owner-root" 
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/*.conf" 
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/*.owner-root" 
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/*.conf" 
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/*.owner-root" 
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/trade/*.conf"  
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/trade/tradekandi.com/*.conf"

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 69.65.42.153:443>
ServerName tradekandi.com
ServerAlias www.tradekandi.com
DocumentRoot /home/trade/public_html
ServerAdmin webmaster@tradekandi.com
UseCanonicalName Off
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/tradekandi.com combined
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/tradekandi.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
## User nobody # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
    suPHP_UserGroup nobody nobody
</IfModule>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/trade/public_html/cgi-bin/
SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/tradekandi.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/tradekandi.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/tradekandi.com.cabundle
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/tradekandi.com-ssl_log combined
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
<Directory "/home/trade/public_html/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

If it's relevant, this is a dedicated server running CentOS & I am also using it to host one PHP-based site.

Wsgi file:

```
import os
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from site import addsitedir
sys.path.append('/home/trade/sites/tradekandi.com.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "../../")))

from django.conf import settings
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "trade.settings"

sys.path.insert(0, join(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

extra.conf with mod_wsgi directives:

```
Alias /static/ /home/trade/public_html/static/

<Directory /home/trade/public_html/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess trade python-path=/home/trade/sites/tradekandi.com.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup trade

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/trade/sites/tradekandi.com.env/site/trade/deploy/pinax.wsgi

<Directory /home/trade/sites/tradekandi.com.env/site/trade/deploy>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: We need to see more of the HTTPd configuration.

Comment: Which file contains the mod_wsgi directives?

Comment: No, the mod_wsgi directives. `WSGIScriptAlias` et alia.

Comment: oh, I forgot about that. that's in my extra.conf, which I import into the conf by using /scripts/ensure_vhost_includes --user=trade. pasted contents above

Comment: Exactly which Include directive is the one importing the extra.conf?

Comment: it's this line: Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/*.conf"

Comment: If that is true then mod_wsgi would stop Apache starting up and give an error about mod_wsgi daemon process group name having been used before. IOW, the name for WSGIDaemonProcess group must be unique but your config suggests you would be including it twice into different parts of Apache configuration. If it isn't then your 443 virtual host may not even be active.

Comment: sorry Graham, it's actually this: "Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/trade/tradekandi.com/*.conf". I saw an answer from you on someone else's question about that unique name issue, but I haven't had that error since trying to set up SSL (had it once a while ago but resolved it). Maybe my 443 virtual host isn't active then. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for the benefit of anyone who may come across this:

I added the following lines:

```
WSGIProcessGroup tradek

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/trade/sites/tradekandi.com.env/site/trade/deploy/pinax.wsgi
```

to a .conf file located in /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/ssl/2/trade/tradekandi.com, then used the command /scripts/ensure_vhost_includes --user=trade

(I also happened to change the ProcessGroup name)

Seems to have done the trick, although now I need to get rid of the insecure elements on the page! Thanks to Graham, because it was one of your answers to someone else that helped me figure this out.